# Facebook Account Kit Collision with Google play services gradle

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-account-kit

After configuring account kit sdk as

```
  compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
```

and gradle sync it conflict with `com.google.android.gms gradle` as **mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes** and my app crash as

> Firebase API initialization failure.
>                                                   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at ...

the above error is due to mixing google play services gradle (I think Google play services gradle may be used by Facebook Account Kit SDK) because I have same version for all Google play services gradles.

And one more crash is coming from Facebook Account Kit SDK side as

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5260)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4808)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:99)
                                                       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.initialize(AccountKitController.java:592)
                                                       at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider.onCreate(AccountKitInitProvider.java:31)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4808) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

But after removing

```
  compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
```

my app working without any issue.
But to integrate Facebook Account Kit in my app I have to include above gradle which conflict with google play services.

Totally disappointed, please help.

---

After upgrading Firebase Gradle as

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

its not colliding but still gives above `RuntimeException` from Account Kit SDK.

Comment: I have faced this problem before with another library (not Picasso). It happens because Facebook Account Kit SDK is using an older version of some libraries than you are. I have couple of suggestions that can help you fix the problem. But for me to fully understand, can you post the build.gradle(app) of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Unable to get provider RuntimeException** exception it seems that, **Application** is not initialized first, **Content Providers** are initialized before it.
And in Facebook account kit SDK's code it was trying to get my application context.

Now the problem was, I did implement method `getApplicationContext()` in application class that is getting application shared variable but that variable was setting globally and Facebook Account Kit sdk code getting Null application context.

Solution : setting shared variable in onCreate method instead of setting globally it resolved the problem of **Unable to get provider**.

And For **Mixing issue**, Account Kit SDK use **11.0.1** version for play services gradle and in my project I am having **11.0.4** that is actually not the issue because on compile time gradle takes latest gradle but In my project I am not referring below gradle which Facebook Account Kit SDK is using.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.1'
```

**Solution** : I have added above gradle with version **11.0.4** and the mixing gradle issue has been resolved.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.4'
```

---

And as [suggested by @astryk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231973/991085) if I exclude `play-services-auth-api-phone` module then  gradle mixing error is not showing but it is not including that module becasue in **AccountKitActivity** on next button click my application crashes as

```
Crash Report Thread:main Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/SmsRetriever;
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.createSmsToken(PhoneLoginController.java:250)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.logIn(PhoneLoginController.java:188)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.LoginManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(LoginManager.java:372)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.logInWithPhoneNumber(AccountKitController.java:631)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneLoginFlowManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(PhoneLoginFlowManager.java:57)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ActivityPhoneHandler.onPhoneLoginComplete(ActivityPhoneHandler.java:189)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity$1.onReceive(AccountKitActivity.java:176)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappList item -1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 16 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available`
```

Answer (score 11):

To fix this you can do something like the following

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.27.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth-api-phone'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

That would remove the stale support gms library from Facebook's SDK and then swap in the same version of the lib that Firebase is using.

Comment: This sounds most appropriate

Comment: @astryk after implement your solution mixing issue resolved, but it crash on AccountKit activity. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the conflict of libraries can be the reason. See dependencies here;
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/account-kit-sdk/4.27.0

See if you could submit an issue with the facebook to update it.

Or if you need facebook for authentication only, you can use [Facebook Android Sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.27.0)

[image]

Comment: I need Facebook Account Kit for Mobile number Login and also Please note that I am already using FB Login via Facebook Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

What feature/service from firebase r u using , can u pls share the snippet of ur gradle dependencies for the same to better understand the problem here?

Comment: I am using firebase messaging as `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
`

Comment: and if i may ask, have u already tried with the latest version com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0 ? and just one more point: pls have a look on these posts in-case u haven't earlier: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/firebase-talk/qrb1gWBKO3M https://atimothee.github.io/blog/2016/09/17/how-to-use-facebook-account-kit-to-authenticate-firebase-app-users-on-android/

Comment: I did test with version 11.4.0 also with no success and 11.6.0 is yesterday's build release.

Comment: Pls ignore the bad formatting in my earlier comment & have a look on these posts in-case u haven't earlier:  [https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/firebase-talk/qrb1gWBKO3M]  [https://atimothee.github.io/blog/2016/09/17/how-to-use-facebook-account-kit-to-authenticate-firebase-app-users-on-android/]

Comment: Thanks to reply............did check with Urls.As discussed with first I already have setup App in Facebook and in second it is not  using Account kit gradle.

Comment: If I am getting it correclty form your comment by "first: u mean the first link &   same as for "second", then the Second link has a link to its github src(https://github.com/atimothee/accountkit-firebase-auth-android/blob/master/app/build.gradle) which has added Account kit dependency along with firbase-auth

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'  
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
  This is the snippet from my gradle file & it just syncs fine, without any warning like " as mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes"

Comment: Thanks to reply...let me check.

Comment: I tried integrating Facebook Account kit in my App today along with SMS login, below is the gradle file snippet i used:      compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'      I dindn't faced any such issue/conflicts with dependencies & app ran just fine. Kindly please share the elaborated code sample to check it in detail/further for the specific issue u r facing.  And Fyi..My IDE is AS 3.0 & device is Android 7.0

Comment: Thanks to reply please check code https://scontent.fbom8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2087-6/10000000_1467820776661335_8130798245845663744_n.zip?oh=9403deb96c518ec48c9d85f196f2d8f8&oe=5A9910E4 and Please find changes in **ctdev-npe** branch.