# Facebook accout kit Firebase API initialization failure

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, account-kit

After implementing **Facebook Account Kit** and run project it shows  **Firebase API initialization failure** as

```
FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758)
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733)
 at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5257)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4808)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

And also getting **Null Pointer Exception** from **AccountKitController** as

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
 at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:101)
 at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.initialize(AccountKitController.java:601)
 at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider.onCreate(AccountKitInitProvider.java:31)
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758)
 at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5257)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4808) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1436) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Using Account kit gradle as

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.27.0'
```

And Firebase Gradle as

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Note : Removing Account Kit from project its working fine i.e. there is no **Firebase API initialization failure.** issue. Therefore it's sure that there is conflict in firebase and Account kit SDK (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **NullPointerException** exception it seems that, **Application** is not initialized first, **Content Providers** are initialized before it.
And in Facebook account kit SDK's code it was trying to get my application context.

Now the problem was, I did implement method `getApplicationContext()` in application class that is getting application shared variable but that variable was setting globally and Facebook Account Kit sdk code getting Null application context.

Solution : setting shared variable in onCreate method instead of setting globally it resolved the problem of **Unable to get provider**.

And For **Mixing issue**, Account Kit SDK use **11.0.1** version for play services gradle and in my project I am having **11.0.4** that is actually not the issue because on compile time gradle takes latest gradle but In my project I am not referring below gradle which Facebook Account Kit SDK is using.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.1'
```

**Solution** : I have added above gradle with version **11.0.4** and the mixing gradle issue has been resolved.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.4'
```

And as [suggested by @astryk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231973/991085) if I exclude `play-services-auth-api-phone` module then  gradle mixing error is not showing but it is not including that module becasue in **AccountKitActivity** on next button click my application crashes as

```
Crash Report Thread:main Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/SmsRetriever;
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.createSmsToken(PhoneLoginController.java:250)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.PhoneLoginController.logIn(PhoneLoginController.java:188)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.LoginManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(LoginManager.java:372)
at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.logInWithPhoneNumber(AccountKitController.java:631)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneLoginFlowManager.logInWithPhoneNumber(PhoneLoginFlowManager.java:57)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.ActivityPhoneHandler.onPhoneLoginComplete(ActivityPhoneHandler.java:189)
at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity$1.onReceive(AccountKitActivity.java:176)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappList item -1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 16 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Facebook's SDK being packaged with a different version of the GMS library than what is packaged with Firebase's. You can do something like this to get back up and running:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.27.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth-api-phone'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
```

What this does is essentially hot-swaps out the older library for the newer one packaged with Firebase. It tells Facebook to compile without the old libs and then we make sure they are added back in with newer version right after.

Comment: after implement your solution mixing issue resolved, but it crash on AccountKit activity. Please see my answer.