# Facebook Account Kit not working with com.google.android.gms gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, facebook-android-sdk

Why Facebook AccountKitActivity not performing and show blank screen in one project but its working fine with another project the gradle dependency for my not working code is here

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/commons-cli-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/pwlocal-sdk.jar')
compile group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub-gson', version: '4.14.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.28.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.0'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.10'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

here is the log

```
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.ProxyRequest>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/zza;
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (AccountKitActivity.java:348)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6754)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2652)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2760)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1507)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6184)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:898)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:788)
11-13 16:10:14.295 19124-19124/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.techno.users.plikits-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.techno.users.plikits-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.techno.users.plikits-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (AccountKitActivity.java:348)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6754)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1119)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2652)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2760)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1507)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6184)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:898)
11-13 16:10:14.296 19124-19124/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:788)
```

[Here is the link for an Question asked before this i think!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47257821/5068500) 
can anyone out there can solve my issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using progaurd?

Comment: Yes i'm using progard

Answer (score 0):

I know it´s late, but did you try it with version: 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0' ?

I had exactly the same issue and it´s working well with this version.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0'
```